# Failed to convert object of type <class 'function'> to Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am trying to randomize the flip augmentation using tensorflow's left_right and up_down augmentation function. I am getting error mapping the function based on the boolean condition via tf.cond()

```
random_number=tf.random_uniform([],seed=seed)
print_random_number=tf.print(random_number)
flip_strategy=tf.less(random_number,0.5)
```

## version 0.1

```
image=tf.cond
        (
            flip_strategy,
            tf.image.flip_left_right(image),
            tf.image.flip_up_down(image),
        )
```

## version 0.2

```
image=tf.cond
            (
                flip_strategy,
                lambda: tf.image.flip_left_right(image),
                lambda: tf.image.flip_up_down(image),
            )
```

## ERROR

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: . Consider casting elements to a supported type.ROR:

Let me know what am I missing or if more info is needed.

Comment: What is `image` in your code? (before the `tf.cond`)

Comment: @jdehesa it's a float32 tensor of dimension(height,width,3)
And it was decoded using tf.image.decode_image(), and originally it was jpeg_image

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/less):

> tf.math.less(
>       x,
>       y,
>       name=None
>   )
>
> Args:
>
> ```
> x: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, half, uint32, uint64.
>
> y: A Tensor. Must have the same type as x.
>
> name: A name for the operation (optional).
> ```

So tf.less expects two tensors, but one of the arguments you pass is a numpy array. You could just convert the numpy array in tensor like

---

```
random_number=tf.random_uniform([],seed=seed)
print_random_number=tf.print(random_number)
random_numer=tf.convert_to_tensor(random_number,dtype=tf.float32)
flip_strategy=tf.less(random_number,0.5)

image=tf.cond`
  (
  flip_strategy,
  tf.image.flip_left_right(image),
  tf.image.flip_up_down(image),
  )
```

---

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, TensorFlow automatically converts arguments to tensors in about every of its functions.

Comment: Yeah thanks for reverting max, but I believe that is not the issue here, as in my previous code it was and there was no such error, only after introducing tf.cond() I am facing the error. And as @jdehesa pointed tensorflow takes care of that.